# Spring integration DefaultMessageListenerContainer blocks when in other module, but doesn't in tests

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I have core module which contains services and some Spring Integration pipelines along with JMS DefaultMessageListenerContainer

---

When I use core module as a dependency for my test project where I have Spring based tests, then upon test termination, all resources are released (not sure whether forcefully)

My tests are annotated with:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ServiceConfig.class)
```

whereas `ServiceConfig` imports all necessary configs from core module

---

When I use core module in another module as the dependency and I spin up Spring app with configuration from core module, `DefaultMessageListenerContainer-1` thread blocks indefinetely

```
@Configuration
@Import({
        ServiceConfig.class
})
public class MyConfig {
}
```

How come test is able to close spring context, but it doesn't work in other module? What's the difference?

Comment: Some simple Boot application to play from our side? Sorry, otherwise your question isn't clear. Not enough info to figure out. Typically during context close the `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` is stopped

Comment: Blocks where? You need to take a thread dump.

Comment: DefaultMessageListenerContainer-1 continuously logs messages:

DEBUG org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSession - ID:N0919-51788-1475011241561-3:6:1 Transaction Commit :null

Comment: From time to time, I can see 

[ActiveMQ Broker[localhost] Scheduler] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue - queue://someQueue expiring messages ..
and another batch of DefaultMessageListenerContainer log messages above

Comment: My connectionFactory looks like:


return new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("vm://localhost?broker.persistent=false&broker.useJmx=false&broker.useShutdownHook=true");


I tried to broker.useShutdownHook as the workaround, but no success.
It seems DefaultMessageListenerContainer doesn't stop

Comment: @ArtemBilan I will try to put together concise boot app